# Format large drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

My situation:

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2

/dev/sdb1 - ~4TB
```

I need to format the drive /dev/sdb1
What do I need to format / clear the data from such a large drive?
What command?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which filesystem you want to use, for example using `ext4`:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to recreate the file system:

```
sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
```

From `man mkfs`:

```
mke2fs is used to create an ext2, ext3, or ext4 filesystem, usually in a disk
partition.  device is the  special file corresponding to the device 
(e.g /dev/hdXX).  blocks-count is the number of blocks on the device.  If omit‐
ted, mke2fs automagically figures the file system size.  If called as mkfs.ext3 
a journal is created as  if  the -j option was specified.

The  defaults of the parameters for the newly created filesystem, if not over-
ridden by the options listed below, are controlled by the /etc/mke2fs.conf
configuration file.  See the mke2fs.conf(5) manual page for more details.
```